# молчать conjugation

Tags: глаголы

Why does молчать verb belong to second conjugation? According to for example https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Russian_verbs all verbs ending with -ать except держать, слышать, дышать belong to the first conjugation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This wiktionary entry is wrong, there are many more conjugation II verbs ending in *-ать* than listed there: *журчать, кричать, мычать* etc.

They probably only list the verbs which don't have stress on the ending in corresponding forms (*молчи́т, кричи́т* but *слы́шит, ды́шит*), which makes it hard to tell the conjugation, as *и* and *е* are phonetically indistinguishable in Russian in that position.

Comment: So is there any way to doubtlessly determine verb conjugation?

Comment: @MarcinAugustynowicz: You can tell the verb conjugation if you know how to pronounce its, say, 2 sg. form. If its ending is stressed, you're done; if it's not, you should check if  it's one of the exceptions listed in the wiktionary entry, otherwise apply the rules for the infinitive form.

Comment: Jacobson suggested a system for determining conjugation of verbs with stressed present as well in "Russian conjugation".